# Font color changing in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am putting together an HTML email and this one line works in every browser except IE. In IE the text shows up black instead of white. Any ideas?

```
<span style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:24px; color:#fff;"><b>FREE WEBINAR</b></span>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using? It's working in IE 9 and 10

Comment: use their F12 inspector to see which styles have been applied to the span.

Comment: Do you run the app in Standards mode? Actually I can't reproduce your issue with IE10 at all, either running it in Standards mode or not...

Answer (score 1):

IE only accepts 6-digit (#RRGGBB) and 8-digit (#AARRGGBB; for gradients) hex values and named colors, I believe.

Try:

```
color:#ffffff;
```

Comment: This would be a valid answer for IE<9, but it seems OP has the issue with IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some default browser styling is used on the `<b>` tag. If you are using `<b>` to put your text in bold, consider using the `<strong>` HTML tag.

To be sure that the font color is white, add an extra inline styling on the `<strong>` element.

```
<span style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:24px; color:#fff;"><strong style="color: #fff;">FREE WEBINAR</strong></span>
```